# Resolve-DNSName get errors to separate file

Tags: powershell, dns, ps

I'm trying to get all the errors to a separate file so that we can clean up the DNS srv later.

What I do want is to get the error message:

> + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (bonjour.Domainname.com:String) [Resolve-DnsName], Win32Exception
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DNS_ERROR_RCODE_NAME_ERROR,Microsoft.DnsClient.Commands.ResolveDnsName
> Resolve-DnsName : Domainname.com : DNS-namnet does not exist

to end up in a separate file, is this possible?

I'm using this script at the moment:

````
$path = ".\domain.txt"
$dnsserver = @('DNS-Srv1', 'DNS-Srv2' , 'DNS-Srv3')
$mxdomain = Get-Content $path
foreach ($domain in $mxdomain) {
Resolve-DnsName -Name $domain -Type MX -Server $dnsserver | select Name,Type,NameExchange } ```
````

Comment: You can enclose the Cmdlet in `try` block and catch the exceptions in `catch`?

Comment: ok, got this far now:
 `foreach ($domain in $mxdomain) { try  {
Resolve-DnsName -Name $domain -Type MX -Server $dnsserver -erroraction stop | select Name,Type,NameExchange }


catch { 
 [BUT WHAT TO TYPE HERE??]
 Export-Csv -Path .\DNS\error_dns.csv -NoTypeInformation
} }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Try Catch` to handle the exception. Within a Catch block, the [current error can be accessed using $_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-7.1#accessing-exception-information) and the object will of [of type `ErrorRecord`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.errorrecord?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0). It has a [`ToString` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.errorrecord.tostring?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0#System_Management_Automation_ErrorRecord_ToString) which you can use to get the string representation of your error record.

```
try {
    Resolve-DnsName -Name www.bing122222.com -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch {
    $error_message = $_.ToString()
    # this will print 'www.bing122222.com : DNS name does not exist'
    Write-Host $error_message 
}
```